# Apache & PHP 5.3.6 on windows 7

Tags: php, html

PHP 5.3.6 & MySQL using this tutorial:

http://www.lynda.com/MySQL-5-tutorials/installing-apache-mysql-and-php/77958-2.html

now when I run my PHP script in Firefox 4 the HTML & PHP runs fine but the PHP error reporting does not work & in IE 8 only the HTML runs, the PHP script just returns a "The website cannot display the page".

Comment: any interesting entries in the apache-logfiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest uninstalling your current setup and doing it the easy way by using wamp. http://www.wampserver.com/en/

> WampServer 2.1a
>    Includes :
>    - Apache 2.2.17
>    - Php 5.3.3
>    - Mysql 5.1.53 (version 64 bits)
>    - Mysql 5.5.8 (version 32 bits)
>    - PhpMyadmin 3.2.0.1
>    - SQLBuddy 1.3.2

It's a simple install and go deal (no fancy configurations needed). It has a nice little command center with easy access to config and log files along with changing settings and restarting everything.

I've never had any hassles with it (installed and used it on xp, vista and win 7 64 bit).

Comment: Agreed. Plus, you can fine tune software, such as upgrading the PHP version as well.

Comment: Very true. You can have multiple versions of everything installed ans switch them on the fly through the mini-command center menu. Makes testing your scripts on a new version easier as you can switch back in seconds if you're having issues.

Comment: Hi I installed XAMPP, I can start apache in XAMPP Control Panel but MySQL just wont start, it says ERROR: MySQL sevice not started [-1]

Comment: I finally installed easyphp.org

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with the compilers used for Apache and PHP. Apache windows binaries are compiled using the VC6 compiler. Up to PHP 5.3.6 you could download Windows binaries compiled with either VC6 or the newer VC9. From PHP 5.3.6 on PHP on Windows is only available compiled with VC9. The kicker is that Apache compiled with VC6 will not work with PHP compiled with VC9. The solution would be to download and install a copy of Apache compile with VC9 from [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/). This version of Apache on Windows will play nicely with PHP compiled with VC9. AFAIK this would explain the problems you're having with PHP not working properly.

HTH.